# Resize other window or application c#

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to resize a window to the resolution 1280x720 with c#. How can I make it? I've tried a lot of codes posted here in stack and the closest result I've got was this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT Rect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int Width, int Height, bool Repaint);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
            foreach (Process p in processes)
            {
                IntPtr handle = p.MainWindowHandle;
                RECT Rect = new RECT();
                if (GetWindowRect(handle, ref Rect))
                    MoveWindow(handle, Rect.left, Rect.right, Rect.right-Rect.left, Rect.bottom-Rect.top + 50, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You have Rect.right where you should have Rect.top, which is why the window moves off the screen sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for your time, really apreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the window to have a size of 1280x720 then use that size in the `MoveWindow` call.

```
  MoveWindow(handle, Rect.left, Rect.top, 1280, 720, true);
```

Comment: Updated my answer, you want to pass the Left and Top to MoveWindow to keep the Window from moving.

Comment: Cool. But How can I center it in the screen after resizing?

Comment: Thanks for your time, really apreciated.

Comment: That code doesn't work. It says Unrecognized escape sequence "\".

Comment: Try with `/`. The `\ ` operator is used in vb.net to return an integer result, and not a floating-point result but it doesn't exist in c#.

Comment: **Edit :** `MoveWindow(handle, (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - 1280) / 2, (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - 720) / 2, 1280, 720, true);`

Comment: Ok, I already had resolved that. Hum... I tested it with a game and the window stays 1272 x 692. I tryed ajusting that and it works. But last night I send it to one of my friends and the resolution is diferent...

Comment: We need to import these statements - 

`[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]`
`static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int Width, int Height, bool Repaint);`

Only then, code runs.

Answer (score 2):

In response to **David Amaral**, to center the window, use this :

```
MoveWindow(handle, (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - 1280) / 2, 
    (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - 720) / 2, 1280, 720, true);
```

By the way, here's the code in vb.net for persons who want :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim processes As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")
    For Each p As Process In processes
        Dim handle As IntPtr = p.MainWindowHandle
        Dim Rect As New RECT()
        If GetWindowRect(handle, Rect) Then
            MoveWindow(handle, (My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 1280) \ 2, (My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Height - 720) \ 2, 1280, 720, True)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure RECT
    Public left As Integer
    Public top As Integer
    Public right As Integer
    Public bottom As Integer
End Structure

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowRect(hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef Rect As RECT) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function MoveWindow(hWnd As IntPtr, X As Integer, Y As Integer, Width As Integer, Height As Integer, Repaint As Boolean) As Boolean
End Function
```